# VirtualHost redeclare class

Tags: apache, symfony

I'm using Apache 2.4.10 on ArchLinux x86_64

I have many virtualhost (for each project), with the following template

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot $TMPL_DIRECTORY

        <Directory $TMPL_DIRECTORY>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

    ServerName $TMPL_NAME
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/${TMPL_NAME}-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/${TMPL_NAME}-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

where `$TMPL_DIRECTORY` is the path to project web dir and `TMPL_NAME` is the url

after append the url to my hosts file are work fine

now i have two projects

- project1.symfony.local (/home/rkmax/Development/project1)
- project2.symfony.local (/home/rkmax/Development/project2)

i'm working in the project1 when i wan switch to project2 always i get a error

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Cannot redeclare class Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Annotation\Target in /home/rkmax/Development/project1/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/Annotation/Target.php line 31
```

i cant understand why read from **project1** that file i must restart apache and everything works fine again

### Update

I have enable the following php extensions

- apc
- apcu
- XCache
- XCache Cacher
- Xdebug
- Zend OPcache

Answer (score 0):

Long shot, but I think it might be the following:

In your `web/app.php` of both applications you are using `ApcClassLoader`. The `ApcClassLoader` gets a cache prefix. The code looks something like this.

```
$loader = new ApcClassLoader('sf2', $loader);
$loader->register(true);
```

Now, as [per the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/performance.html#caching-the-autoloader-with-apc), if you run different instances of the same application on the same server, you must change the prefix in at least one of them.

So, the code in the `web/app.php` files should look like this:

```
// in the first instance
$loader = new ApcClassLoader('sf2_app1', $loader);
$loader->register(true);

// in the second instance
$loader = new ApcClassLoader('sf2_app2', $loader);
$loader->register(true);
```

Of course, don't forget to do the same in `web/app.php.dist`, in case you're using it for deployment.

After that, restart Apache once more, to make sure that the cached web/app.php files are flushed (in case you're using APC with `stat=0`).

Comment: no i'm not using the ApcClassLoader and i'm using only the dev environment

Comment: Thanks for your comment made me think that extensions are php cache. I do not know why both are active at the time apc and xcache. disable opcache and xcache and now are working fine